# React Native How to keep memory after force quitting the app

Tags: react-native, expo

I deployed my app on TestFlight for beta and i came across 2 major bugs.

My app begins with a welcome screen that I only want to show the user the first time they use the app.

Whenever I force quit the app or background the app for large amount of time it reloads the app back to the welcome screen.

How do i make it that after force quitting or just being off the app for a little while the app would remember to skip the welcome screen.

The idea is the user never sees the welcome or any of those screens again. Is this a memory issue? I am using react navigation to navigate as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this with local storage.  I have the same system as you and i use redux with redux persist.  I save a flag that the welcome screen has been seen in redux and then use redux persist to make sure that when they close and reopen the app the value will still be there.

if you don't want to use redux/redux persist then you could use good old async  storage for this.

Comment: Would async storage just work as simple like, in App.is when the app is loading up check is a user logged in- if yes navigate to the home screen otherwise, the welcome screen? but how would the App know a user logged  in previously, if after x amount of time it resets? what would i be saving in local storage?

Comment: Im a little confused, if in my login screen i save data in async storage, could i then access the storage in a different file?

Comment: yes you can access asyncstorage values from any file, even on app start during splash screen.  If you use redux persist, that's the whole point of redux is that you can access values from anywhere in the app